# Anim.js - what to enter as target when I only want the trigger the hovered elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, anime.js

I'm trying to use anime.js to animate elements within a div called .grid-item
It's a simple hover animation where text and an icon animate in when the user hovers. The .grid-item is duplicated within a Mansory grid and this is where it all breaks down.The idea is of course that only the children of the hovered .grid-item are affected.At the moment all the .grid-item's are triggered.

When I remove the anime function and use $(this) to manipulate a CSS attribute, everything works fine. I can't seem to figure out what to enter as a target within the anime function. Any help would be much appreciated!

html

```
<div class="grid-item">
 <div class="grid-container">
  <div class="tl-item-rollover-wrapper">
    <img class="tl-svg-magnify" src="icons/icon.svg">
  </div>

  <div class="tl-item-copy-wrapper">
    <div class="tl-item-project-title">Line--01</div>
    <div class="tl-item-project-info">Line--02</div>
  </div>

  <div class="tl-category-wrapper">
    <i class="material-icons">cloud_queue</i>
  </div>

   <img class="tl-item-image" src="images/image.jpg"/>

 </div>
</div>
```

javascript (what i have now)

```
$('.grid-item').hover(function() {
   anime ({
   targets: ['.tl-item-image', this],
   scale: 1.1,
   opacity: 0.6,
   easing: 'easeInOutQuart',
   duration: 700 
  });
}, function() {
   anime ({
   targets: ['.tl-item-image', this],
   scale: 1,
   opacity: 1,
   easing: 'easeInOutQuart',
   duration: 700 
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.grid-item').hover(function() {
   anime ({
   targets: [this.querySelector('.tl-item-image'), this.querySelector('.another-element')],
   scale: 1.1,
   opacity: 0.6,
   easing: 'easeInOutQuart',
   duration: 700 
  });
}, function() {
   anime ({
   targets: [this.querySelector('.tl-item-image'), this.querySelector('.another-element')],
   scale: 1,
   opacity: 1,
   easing: 'easeInOutQuart',
   duration: 700 
   });
});
```

Obviously, remove `, this.querySelector('.another-element')` and the square brackets if you don't need to animate more than one internal element.

I used `this.querySelector`, as `this` refers to the currently hovered `.grid-item`. I used `querySelector` to select the child element and also because anime is a Javascript library and doesn't except jQuery objects.

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/rxcdayLz/20/